# DynamicData Transform vs ReactiveUi Select

Tags: dynamic-data, reactiveui

If I understand well, DynamicData Transform is equivalent to ReactiveUi Select.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty similar, transform have a few extra options for performance based reasons but otherwise essentially the same